# How do display event cards when push a button

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I'm doing reminder IOS app.How do display event card push a button?

event add view.[Home.swift]
[Home.push plus circle button open this view.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQn92.png)

event card display on Home.[EventList.swift]
[event cards.this cards do display on Home.swift][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS0LG.png)

I tried save tapCount to userDefaults.in **EventList.swift** get tapCount.Because use ForEach scope.

**Home.swift**

```
var tapCount = 0

Button(action: {}) {
    tapCount += 1

    UserDefaults.standard.set.....
}
```

**EventList.swift**

```
var body: some View {
        let tapCount: Int16 = UserDefault.standard.Integer(...) as! Int16

        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0 ..< tapCount) { item in
                    EventView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But not to do.please teach it.

Answer (score 0):

My yesterday solution for using `UserDefaults.standart` in SwiftUI:

1. made `final class UserData` with needed variable;
2. set this variable from `UserDefaults` at the `init()`;
3. set `@EnvironmentObject var` of `UserData` class at needed View;

some quick example:

```swift
import SwiftUI

final class UserData: ObservableObject {

    @Published var tapCount: Int? { // remember, it can be nil at the first launch!
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(tapCount, forKey: "tapCount")
        }
    }

    init() {
        // Sure you can set it to 0 with UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "tapCount") ?? 0, but be careful with your ForEach loop
        self.tapCount = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "tapCount")
    }

}

// how to use:
struct SomeView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserDataSettings

    var body: some View {

        if self.userData.tapCount == nil {
            return AnyView(Text("no taps!"))
        } else {
            return AnyView(ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    // you need to check for nil, else you app may crash. this if...else variant should work
                    ForEach(0 ..< userData.tapCount!) { item in
                        Text("\(item)")
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }

}
```

and the last thing: you need to set `.environmentObject(UserData())` when display your view (in `SceneDelegate` for example, if this is the first view) and then bring this `userData` variable to other child views)

Comment: Thanks you! I was do your code.I get a new error. **Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type** Do you know resolution this error?

Comment: @Kazu_Japanese, check code updates, now it has no errors at my xCode (I've also replaced ```EventView``` with ```Text("\(item)")```

Comment: @Kazu_Japanese, you're welcome, glad if this solution helps you